# Editing an Entry does not update

Tags: entry, saving

I'm trying to edit an entry and the page seems to simply refresh, not displaying the usual submitted page that shows made changes etc. I cannot figure out what could be causing this. Hopefully the community will, thanks in advance.

I'm running EE 2.2.2 hopefully I don't have to update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes this is caused by a validation on one of the other tabs on your publish page. You might not see them if you're on a different tab.

Comment: I looked through each tab then tried again and it saved... Thanks Jeremy.